# Conditional Formatting working selectively in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to make it so text crosses itself out when a checkbox is crossed in Google Sheets. The condition works as intended for one cell, but does not work for the others at all despite being defined in the exact same range.

[image]

I've tried rewriting the conditions a handful of times and trying to redefine the range but nothing really seemed to want to budge. So far only the first cell in the range has any response to the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with

*Apply to range:*   **A2:F**

*Custom formula:*. **`=$G2`**